# Complicated vector layer's style in OpenLayer 2

Tags: openlayers-2

Is it possible to style vector layer so there would be picture and label with its own background color for a feature? Something like this:

[image]

Comment: If style properties can be mapped to feature properties you can use a stylemap as in this example http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/vector-features-with-text.html (view source to see how it's done) otherwise you could loop through features and style them individually `feature.style = { ... }`  where the style object is a set of key name and value pairs, see 
http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Feature/Vector-js.html#OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style  for all the available options

Comment: And how to put colored rectangle under label? If I simply increase labelOutlineWidth, it looks bad.

Comment: You could probably use externalGraphic for the main image and backgroundGraphic with its own offsets for a label background.  Instead of having to find physical image files for each color you could use one pixel data urls generated by http://png-pixel.com/ and stretch them by setting whatever backgroundWidth and backgroundHeight you want (maybe based on the number of characters in the text).